Changing font styles for all charts
I'm trying to get my code to change the chart style for all charts. I have managed this for tables, but if I alter the code for charts it doesn't work. Am I missing something? This is the code for tables that works, and it seems to fall over as the Apply Style must use a different style for charts.
Table Code
If oSh.HasTable Then
  Set oTbl = oSh.Table
  oTbl.ApplyStyle ("{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}"), True
End If

I tried the following code
If oSh.HasChart Then
  Set oChr = oSh.Chart
  oChr.ApplyStyle ("{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}"), True
End If

But I get the error

Complile Error :- Method or data member not found.

The table code moves the style to Medium Style 2, Accent 1. I'm expecting charts to have the same effect.

WHERE do you get that error?  Which line?

Apologies, the error is on this line    oChr.ApplyStyle ("{5C22544A-7EE6-4342-B048-85BDC9FD1C3A}"), True

Chart objects do not include a style that would allow you to set a new font. Is the new font included in the presentation font theme, or are you trying to set other fonts that are not in the presentation theme? The syntax is different.


Using ChartSytle to change style

Microsoft documentation:

Chart.ChartStyle property (PowerPoint)


If the chart is selected,

Sub ChartSytle()
    Dim shp As Shape
    With ActiveWindow.Selection
        If .ShapeRange.HasChart = msoTrue Then
            Set shp = .ShapeRange(1)
            shp.Chart.ChartStyle = 12  ' 1 to 48, modify as needed
        End If
    End With
End Sub


If chart is not selected

Sub ChartSytle()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1) ' modify as needed
    With shp
        If .HasChart = msoTrue Then
            shp.Chart.ChartStyle = 12  ' 1 to 48, modify as needed
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Thank you, I tried it but get Run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)': Selection (unknown member) : Invalid request. Nothing appropriate is currently selected when it gets to If .ShapeRange.HasChart = msoTrue Then

Select the chart before execute the code, or use the 2nd snippet.

Thank you so much, that works perfectly. Is there a way to also set it to colorful pallete 1 in the code? It will then do exactly what is needed.

What's colorful pallete 1?

When you select a chart, go to Chart Design, then select change colours. It's the first default option under the theme.
